# How to fetch records by time with ASC order?

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, ms-access

I am new to C# WinApp and I am working on it. In a Winform, I want to fetch data from MS Access database to DataGridView. I wrote a query for fetching records of employees logged in with time ascending order but it is not showing in proper order.

First let me tell you the parameteres I am using.
table field is Date/Time in MS Access and format is Medium Time. the time is recorded in the field as '09:15 AM'. the date and the time are in different fields.
the query is...

```
"Select EmpName, EmpDesig, EmpTime from LogReg Where TheDate=' "+DateTime.Today.To.ShortDateString()+" ' Order By EmpTime ASC
```

the output result in time field shows the time in ascending order but it shows as `'30/12/1899 05:30:00'` I want it only as `"05:30 PM"`. in data table the time is saved as `"05:30 PM"` only then why it displays as `'30/12/1899 05:30:00'`?

Answer (score 0):

Store and use dates as date values, not strings:

```
"Select EmpName, EmpDesig, EmpTime from LogReg Where TheDate = #"+ DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# Order By EmpTime ASC"
```

or, why not use the internal function for today's date:

```
"Select EmpName, EmpDesig, EmpTime from LogReg Where TheDate = Date() Order By EmpTime ASC"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. sir, my problem is the time field (date and time are saved in different fields). date is showing proper. the time data stored in db is '05:30 PM' but it displays as '30/12/1899 05:30:00'. what should I make the changes in the query to get the db time as it is, '05:30PM'? by the way, the dataset is fetched in a DataGridView.

Comment: That seems correct. 1899-12-30 is the "zero" date value. So, set a format when you display the values, say, h:MM.

Comment: Understood the h:MM but where to add the h:MM in my query and how? any other function like DateTime or else required?

Comment: The query retrieves the data. In your form, you apply the format needed.

Answer (score 0):

Store your retrieved value in a datetime variable if you are already not.
You can then format the way you want to display it. The following will display your desired format.

```
DateTime dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(someValuefromDB);
dateValue.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```

From query you can achieve the same like so

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(YourColumn AS TIME),100) from YourTable
```

Comment: It's not working. the records may be 5, 10, 25 or more and it's showing in a DataGridView. so, I need a loop which can convert this datetime into time and display in a desired column. another way there should be function in a query that brings only the time from db and display in the DGV column.

Comment: use the above code inside a loop with values from database. the point is when you are assigning the value to datatable, just use value.ToString("hh:mm tt"). 
I am editing my above answer to achieve the same from query. assuming you are using MSSQL

Comment: No. as mentioned in my post, I am using C# WinApp with MS Access database. varchar is not there. :)

Comment: How about using the dateValue.ToString("hh:mm tt") format? did you try it ?

Comment: the value comes from db into a dataset. my requirement is to split the time from date & time and to show only time with AM/PM. the value I get from db is like, dsEmpLogIn.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString(). ToString("hh:mm tt") will not work. I have been tried Convert, DateTime, TryParse etc. but everything throws some exception.

Comment: Kindly post your code so that you can be assisted accordingly

Comment: Hi, I just get it done by adding... `dgvEmpLogIn.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm tt";` to my DGV. this code splits time from date and displays only time. Thank You for your help too.

Comment: Hi, is this post need to be closed? if so, i don't see any 'Accept' or 'Close' option on my page.